# Improve Autolayout Code

Tags: ios, autolayout

When adding a view programatically, is there a more concise way of fitting it to the parent view than the below?

```
NSDictionary *views = @{ @"view" : view };
NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[view]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[view]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[parentView addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
[parentView addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using any extra dependencies the most concise version of your code is this:

```
NSDictionary *views = @{ @"view" : view };
[parentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[parentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

(You don't need to have the array variables, zero padding assumed and H: is the default axis value).

You could use my [auto layout convenience category](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout) which would allow the following:

```
[view pinToSuperviewEdges:JRTViewPinAllEdges inset:0];
```

Comment: you have no idea how you made me laugh xD. I guess you can reduce a little more with the suggestion from @uchuugaka to omit the dashes and zeros

Comment: Aw I'm not down voting anyone for DSLs. I just don't see the ROI in a lot of cases.

Comment: @uchuugaka I was mostly joking. Mostly. We've had _massive_ ROI on using my category - I'm almost _too_ dependent on it now.

Comment: Only complaint is that your category doesn't namespace prefix the methods. This is risky long term if the class itself gets methods added with the same names in the future. Always a risk with categories on classes that are widely inherited. Otherwise it looks nice for the common stuff actually. A category like this is not a DSL, but a category of convenience methods.

Comment: Up vote for a mostly great category approach with nice documentation.

Comment: Okay cool, disappointing there is no less verbose method, but agree a simple category is a nice solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, you code improve slightly, though no more correct by using NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings() to creat your views dictionary. 
If you want zero spaced constraints between a view edge and the corresponding superview edge, you can omit the dashes and zeros from the VFL strings.

Beyond that you would need to use a DSL which means something else to learn and still understand and debug in terms of the true form.